# Define complex data structure type in React.JS property definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a typescript data file which is consumed by my react component. The Typescript data file named data.ts has following data item:

contents of data.ts

```
export default {
    nodes: [
      { name: 'Myriel', group: 1 },
      { name: 'Napoleon', group: 1 },
      { name: 'Mlle.Baptistine', group: 1 },
    ],
    links: [
      { source: 1, target: 0, value: 1 },
      { source: 2, target: 0, value: 8 },
      { source: 3, target: 0, value: 10 },
   ],
};
```

I am passing that data to a react component (graph.tsx) from another component main.tsx.

Relevent contents of main.tsx

```
import data from "./data";
import Graph from "./Graph";
.
.
.
return <Graph width={width} height={height} data={data} />;
```

Now on Graph.tsx the props interface is defined below:

```
interface IProps {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  data: {
    nodes: { name: string; group: number }[];
    links: { source: number; target: number; value: number }[];
  };
}
```

Now I want to change the data to following format

in data2.ts

```
export default {
root : [
    {name: "flare",
    children: [{
      name: "analytics",
      children: [{
        name: "cluster",
        children: [{
          name: "AgglomerativeCluster",
          size: 3938
        }, {
          name: "CommunityStructure",
          size: 3812
        }, {
          name: "HierarchicalCluster",
          size: 6714
        }, {
          name: "MergeEdge",
          size: 743
        }]
      }, {
        name: "graph",
        children: [{
          name: "BetweennessCentrality",
          size: 3534
        }, {
          name: "LinkDistance",
          size: 5731
        }, {
          name: "MaxFlowMinCut",
          size: 7840
        }, {
          name: "ShortestPaths",
          size: 5914
        }, {
          name: "SpanningTree",
          size: 3416
        }]
      }, {
        name: "optimization",
        children: [{
          name: "AspectRatioBanker",
          size: 7074
        }]
      }]
    }
]
```

That is the data format in Graph.tsx will be something like this.

```
data:{
 root: {name:string, children: root}[];
};
```

what is the proper format of writing this inside IProps on the light of the older data format (below)?

```
data: {
    nodes: { name: string; group: number }[];
    links: { source: number; target: number; value: number }[];
  };
```

As it is a nested chain of data how to define it in the property definition?

Comment: No sure I understand what you're exactly trying to achieve. Is this a what is a better way of refactoring this code kind of question? or How to define typings for your data input?

Comment: first my suggestion would be to create an interface/model for what ever object is your data.ts is exporting and it must comply to it. then in your props definition you assign the same typing to it.

Comment: @SergioAlen My question is if the data from data.ts can be written as data: {
    nodes: { name: string; group: number }[];} how can I write the same for data2.ts

So it boils down to designing the interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the correct type declaration for your data would be as follows.  Define this recursive type alias:

```
type MyNode = { name: string } & ({ children: MyNode[] } | { size: number });
```

And then use:

```
data: { root: [MyNode] };
```

Comment: I would try that and come back here.